# Have the same IP address for android emulator and Host PC

Tags: android, android-emulator, ip

I would like to know that is there any way we can configure the android emulator to use the same IP address as the Host machine(in my case a Windows machine) by default ? And if yes, than how do I configure that ?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why do you need them to have the same IP?

Comment: It's a SIP based application and the sip server is not able to reply to the emulators IP.

Comment: If you connect to your android emulator from outside, the IP address should be the machine IP address.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the purpose is that you want to connect to your emulator from out side devices.

But this is not called "have the same IP with host PC", you might want to configure the network to bridged mode in your emulator. Thus you can get an IP address which is in the same subnet of your host PC.

However, I would like you to try a better way to achieve the same goal, check this:

```
adb forward <local> <remote> - forward socket connections
                               forward specs are one of:
                                 tcp:<port>
                                 localabstract:<unix domain socket name>
                                 localreserved:<unix domain socket name>
                                 localfilesystem:<unix domain socket name>
                                 dev:<character device name>
                                 jdwp:<process pid> (remote only)
```

Comment: Please google adb forward to check if you are using it correctly first. Try: 1. Run your adb in admin/root mode 2. Check if the specific port number is already been occupied.